# Setting posts_per_page for taxonomy term template

Tags: posts, functions, templates, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy term page set up to display posts associated with that term (taxonomy-insight_type-academia.php). I figured I could use the following to limit the posts on that page based on code found here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'academia', 'insight_type' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
} );
```

I have added the term to the taxonomy but it doesn't seem to work. I can get it to work for the taxonomy, but not the term.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taxonomy template you have (`taxonomy-insight_type-academia.php`) is in the form of [(`taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/#custom-taxonomy), and the format for [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) is `is_tax( '<taxonomy>', '<term>' )`, so in your `pre_get_posts` callback, you should:

```php
// Use this.
if ( $query->is_tax( 'insight_type', 'academia' ) )

// Not this.
if ( $query->is_tax( 'academia', 'insight_type' ) )
```

Additionally — to avoid conflict with other queries, you should also check if the current query is the main one or not, and also check if it's an admin-side request.

```php
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()
    && $query->is_tax( 'insight_type', 'academia' )
)
```

You may already know that, but I thought it'd be a good reminder. :)

Comment: So simple, thanks Sally

Comment: Glad it helped and hopefully the extra stuff is useful. :)